# XAML Alternatives

Tags: wpf, xaml, programming-languages

I love WPF, but I hate XAML.

XAML is too verbose, has syntax issues when Microsoft tried to extend it (see StringFormat on Bindings), and is difficult to navigate.

Are there any alternatives to XAML?

(These are just my opinions. Feel free to disagree.)

Comment: Too verbose? I think trying to declare user interfaces in C# is far more verbose than XAML.

Comment: Perhaps, but then I don't consider C# an alternative to XAML. :)

Comment: I was going to ask this same question the other day, but was worried it was going to start a war.  Mine was going to be "Is XAML a step backwards" but you know how that would have gone down.

Comment: I love WPF and normally wouldn't consider going back to Windows Forms, but I am also in the camp that thinks what the hell were they thinking with XAML!  On one hand I can applaud Microsoft for using a standard like XML, but on the hand after using it I wish they had designed a custom UI definition language that had direct support for data binding and all the other 'mini-languages' that you have to use with XAML.

Comment: Sure XAML is a standard... FOR DATA!!! As a language however it sucks balls.

Comment: Ideally Microsoft would have a JSON way of creating UI's. Including long URI's when you're just adding a button is brutal. XML is on the decline for this very reason.

Answer (score 15):

There are alternatives:

XUL, Flash, Delphi resource syntax, C# Form.Designer.cs syntax, VB6 form syntax

Surely there are no **compelling** alternatives though.

*It's like human bodies -- utter rubbish with all its juices and smells but that's by far the best life form known. XAML is clearly really really bad, but there's nothing half as good around.*

Comment: I got the impression that MacFarland wants alternatives to XAML for WPF. If so this is not an answer to his question.

Comment: that doesn't resemble an answer from any point of view. if you want to know, what's better than xaml, think about of JSON, e.g. which is far more readable. or [this](https://github.com/Athari/Alba.Jaml)

Answer (score 6):

XAML does seem to be the elephant in the room. While I'm a huge fan of WPF the verbosity of XAML can be a little hard on the eyes. Whilst Blend and VS2010 go long way to reducing the need for coding XAML from scratch, I still find hand editing a necessity in nearly everything I do.

I find [power boots](http://dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/18/powershell-meet-wpf-via-powerboots/) easy on the eyes and the CSS like syntax of [JavaFX](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1/tutorials/ui/syntax/index.html) to be quite appealing. These seem to be the insparation for D'oh.

However verbose XAML is, at least there is tooling support to get us 90% of the way, any other alternative would take us back to hand coding all the UI. Not an attractive proposition for this coder.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative is to not do the UI at all and have a designer do it in Blend instead.

Comment: Even if you have a designer that can grasp into some code understanding (I have this and consider myself lucky), it it is completetely unprobable that you can free your hands from touching the XAML part.

Answer (score 1):

This might be something to watch.  There is nothing to download from the website yet though.

D'oh: The Super Productive Windows GUI Language

http://doh.xn--majkrsft-e0ab.se/

Comment: The link appears to be dead now.  Oh well it did seem to good to be true.

Answer (score 1):

now I know why your name badge looked familiar at the last Innovation Day.

It would be a lot of work but you could make a small start - there's no reason why you have to use XAML, just need something creating the partial classes.

So, you could code up a DSL replacing XAML with something that was legal C# or go the whole hog and write a VS tool which generated C# the same way the XAML processor does. It depends on how much you want available to the code-behind file at compile-time.

Hmmm, with IronRuby, maybe a DSL in IronRuby

(DSL = Domain Specific Language for anyone reading who is acronymically challenged.)